# Pass parameter to component is readonly ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I have the following component to add comments in a popup. I wanted to pass the car to the component update some values and then the popup closed and the object that was passed from the parent is updated.

When I try to update the car object and try initialize it to be a new array or to update any items I get an error saying its readonly

Here is my code

```
interface ICar
{
    id: string;
    comments: IComment[];
}

interface IComment
{
    name: string;
    comments: string;
}

const carComment = (car: ICar) => {
    const [comm, setComm] = useState<string>("");

    if (comm === "" && car.comments !== undefined && car.comments.length > 0) {
        setComm(car.comments[0].comment);
    }

    const handleSaveClick = () => {
        if (car.comments !== undefined && car.comments.length > 0) {
            car.comments[0].comment = comm;
        }
        else {
            car.comments = new Array<IComment>();
            car.comments.push({ comment: comm, name: "Peter" });
        }

        return (
        <>
            <TextField
                id="testMulti"
                label="Comment"
                multiline
                rows={4}
                defaultValue={comm}
                variant="outlined"
                key={1}
                onChange={e => {
                    setComm(e.target.value);
                }
                }
            />
            <Button onclick ="handleSaveClick"> Save </Button>
            </>
    }   
} 
export default CarComment;
```

Comment: variable props are read only. to update parent you need to add a callback function to `carComment = (car,saveCar)` ,  called on each click on button. this `saveCar` function will update parent state

Comment: @AlainIb thanks for that, do you have an example?

Comment: Or what do i need to modify in my code?

Comment: this look good example 
https://towardsdatascience.com/passing-data-between-react-components-parent-children-siblings-a64f89e24ecf

or this 

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/react-communicating-between-components

Comment: thanks! i will try get it to work and then post my solution

Comment: I must be missing something this is my calling code from the parent                    
   const parentCallBack = (childData: ICar) => {
        const xxx = childData;
    };

<CarComponent id={props.id} comments={props.comments} callback = {parentCallBack}></CarComponent>

Comment: Type '{ id: string; comments: IComment[]; callback: (childData: ICar) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ICar'.
  Property 'callback' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ICar'.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **parent** i added

```
const updateCar = (carComments: IComment[]) => {
...
};

<carComment id={props.id} comments={props.comments} updateCarCallback={updateCar}></carComment>
```

In the **Child** I added

```
interface ICarCommentProps extends ICar {
    updateCarCallback(carComments: IComment[]): void;
}

and in the handleSaveClick i added 
updateCar(car.comments);
```